# How to print certain attributes using CActive record in yii?

Tags: php, yii

How to print certain properties in the model while returning data to user

I have Users model , which has Username, Password, Email

I can get all users username, email

Now i need to send Username and email to user

while trying to send data to the user as json from the following code

```
      $models = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);

    if(is_null($models)) {
        $this->_sendResponse(200, sprintf('No users found'));
    } else {
        $rows = array();

        foreach($models as $model)
        {
            $Users[] = $model->attributes;

        }

        $SandboxObj->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($Users));
    }
```

It shows like `[{"Username":"foo","Email":"foo@foo.com","Password":"null"}]`

I need to send like `[{"Username":"foo","Email":"foo@foo.com"}]`

How to do this in yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
  $models = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);

if(is_null($models)) {
    $this->_sendResponse(200, sprintf('No users found'));
} else {
    $rows = array();

    foreach($models as $model)
    {
        unset($model->attributes['Password']); //add this line
        $Users[] = $model->attributes;

    }

    $SandboxObj->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($Users));
}
```

Or simply don't select Password field in your query if you don't need it .

Comment: @Alizera I Selected only Email, Username but when i use $model->attributes it returns all properties in Users model

Comment: so what is your `$creteria` ?

Comment: @Alizera $criteria->select = "Username,Email";

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is already been answered and accepted but i do not like to teach people the lazy way of coding. there for, as a correction on Alireza Fallah's answer:

```
$models = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);

if(is_null($models)) {
    $this->_sendResponse(200, sprintf('No users found'));
} else {
    $userData = array();

    foreach($models as $model)
    {
        $tempData = new StdClass;
        $tempData->Username = $model->Username;
        $tempData->Email= $model->Email;
        $userData[] = $tempData;
    }

    $SandboxObj->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($userData));
}
```

or as said before only query what you need in the first place, then you can be lazy all you want in the rest of your code.

**Edit**: another way of doing the foreach with less resources is :

```
    foreach($models as &$model)
    {
        $tempData = new StdClass;
        $tempData->Username = $model->Username;
        $tempData->Email= $model->Email;
        $model = $tempData;
    }
```

and then you can use $models in stead of $userData